# How to convert OpenPop.NET MailMessage to System.Net.Mail.MailMessage?

Tags: c#, .net, openpop

Is there any way to convert OpenPop.NET MailMessage to System.Net.Mail.MailMessage?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000954/convert-mime-tree-to-mailmessage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using OpenPop.NET >=version 2, you could just call the [ToMailMessage method](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/documentation/OpenPop~OpenPop.Mime.Message.ToMailMessage.html) that accompanies the [Message class](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/documentation/OpenPop~OpenPop.Mime.Message.html).